# update remote db using dblink_exec fails

Tags: postgresql, exec, dblink

The below statement is failing by saying syntax error, I do not see the syntax error, please help:

```
SELECT dblink_exec(
     'dbname=billing  user=billing password=billing port=5432',
     'insert into md.radacct values('2013-01-01 00:00:00+01:30')');
```

table was created like this

```
create table md.radacct(date_time timestamp with time zone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up your single-quotes inside the outermost single-quotes.

```
select dblink_exec('...', ' insert into ... values(''2013-01-01 ... '')');
```

Comment: Or just use dollar quoting for clarity: `select dblink_exec('...', $$insert into ... values('2013-01-01 ... ')$$);`